# Objective c: How to set the UIImageView image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

hai iam new one for `objective c` and `iOS` development

Set the `UIImageview` image. try the following code

`arrowImgVw is UIImageView Class object`

```
UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]init];
image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"return_journey_denoter.png"];
arrowImgVw.image = image;
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: check the name of your image also its same as the you given...

Comment: Check frame, name of the image

Comment: Did you initialize the variable 'arrowImgVw'?

Comment: If you are running on a device not simulator please add this image not just as a reference but copy it in project too. the code you are using is good please check if arrowImgVw is displayed on screen or not.

Comment: try to add background color in the image and check if the color is displaying?

Answer (score 8):

hey you are wrong in some point use this code for adding an image into UIImageView and display it on iPhone devide

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
```

//Allocating imageView and set its frame.

```
myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"return_journey_denoter.png"];
```

//add image into imageview

```
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
```

// add imageview into your viewcontroller's view

Answer (score 5):

To simply set image to imageView just one line of code

```
arrowImgVw.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"return_journey_denoter.png"];
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you have `written` is ok for `setting image`, just check the `name` for the given image or you can try following code...

```
UIIImageView *arrowImgVw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)]; //just example change the frame as per your need    
arrowImgVw.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"return_journey_denoter"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the image from the assets . Use the below code

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image" inBundle:bundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

image should be inside your assets folder .

Answer (score -1):

In **Swift3.0**

To set image to your imageView use belwo code.

```
arrowImgVw.image = UIImage(named: "return_journey_denoter.png")
```